# Automatic, timed file downloads with WebDriver

Tags: javascript, file, selenium, download, webdriver

I am automating a website with WebDriver but my file download needs are a little different from those I have found when googling.

I have a website which creates orders. When I click the 'place order' button, it redirects me to the Print Order page. As a "convenience" for me, this page automatically launches the download operation in its body onload, meaning that when I click the 'place order' button, I go to a new page and then a file download dialog immediately appears to let me download the generated pdf, thus blocking the browser.

Here are the solutions I found/thought of, and why I couldn't use them:

1. Configure Firefox/Chrome profiles to silently download files. Can't use this because I have the requirement of timing how long the download takes.
2. Override window.open with a function that prevents the download, and allows me to grab the URL and download it with wget. Can't use this because the file download is started from the onload function of the next page, so any javascript I run on this page will be lost.
3. Cancel the onload function or try to execute code before the onload function. Can't find a way to do this in webdriver.
4. Download the print page with wget, modify the html to change the onload handler, and inject the modified html back into selenium. Can't find a way to replace an entire page, including <head> and <body> tag and URL.

Unfortunately I can't change the source code of this website because I am in QA and I don't have that sort of leverage with development. Does anyone have any ideas for a way to download this file in an automatic manner that can be timed?

Thanks.

Comment: I mean you can do it on selenium, I just dont see why, you aren't testing anything on the UI, otherwise I don't think this is really in the selenium realm. This is a pretty open ended question as well. Maybe try narrowing your focus more specifically in the future

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have 2 options.

1. Use an AUTOIT script to download the file once you receive the popup, this tests the functionality of the page opening and the download.
2. Download the file just using http get.  This misses out testing that the page loads but will still check that the file exists.

The other tests you mention above seem to be too complicated.

Comment: Files downloading is possible with selenium webdriver , check this post once http://qaautomationworld.blogspot.in/2014/02/file-downlaoding-using-selenium.html